# Graph of hyperbola appears empty in Desmos: $\left|\left((x+c)^2+y^2\right)^{1/2}-\left((x-c)^2+y^2\right)^{1/2}\right|=2c$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

[image]

I tried to graph a horizontal hyperbola whose $d$ is $2c$. I tried with different graphing tools online and they are all empty? Why?

If $d=2c$, then we know every point on the $y$-axis such that $x\geq \pm c$ is part of the hyperbola. But why is this not shown on any tool that I used? I tried $y=0$ and that is shown.

Comment: Degenerate cases of graphs, especially ones defined by implicit relations, can sometimes fool graphing software. Plotting often occurs by sampling points; degenerate cases require a certain care that automatic sampling can miss. Even if some software happens to recognize a class of equations as special curves (say, conics) and draws them deliberately, degenerate cases may still fool them. The threshold of foolery is an implementation detail you'd have to discuss directly with the developers. Note that you *can* describe the solution set in a way Desmos successfully plots: `y=0{|x|>c}`.